# Problem to using bash shell with another user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sudo, aix

I am trying to use a bash command using another user.

```
sudo su - user -c ' bash -c "echo $SHELL" '
```

Output: /usr/bin/ksh

Does someone know what's happening? Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Why do you think that output is wrong?

Comment: Remember, anything in double quotes is expanded early. `$SHELL` is changed to `/usr/bin/ksh` _before_ bash starts; and inspecting `$SHELL` is not the right way to check which shell is actively running anyhow in the first place (if that is in fact what you intend to do).

Comment: This command is far more complicated than it needs to be. `sudo -u user 'echo $SHELL'` would probably suffice.

Comment: @chepner, need an `-i` or somesuch in there so we aren't looking for `/usr/bin/'echo $SHELL'` or a similarly-named executable elsewhere in the PATH.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I need to execute the command using bash. The ksh shell not woks with this command.

Comment: @AntonioCosta, yes, and `bash -c 'anything'` _does_ execute with bash. `echo $SHELL` is misleading you, for the reasons I describe above; even though it says ksh, it's actually bash that's echoing ksh.

Comment: @AntonioCosta, ...if you show a real command that doesn't work unless you're using bash, then maybe I can provide more concrete advice.

Comment: I think I can show the problem. If I do this ```sudo su - user bash echo $SHELL``` the output is this  /usr/bin/ksh

Comment: Yes, and I already told you `echo $SHELL` is useless. Stop pretending it means anything. **`echo $SHELL` does not tell you which shell is in use.** And it _especially_ doesn't tell you anything useful when you don't quote correctly to cause it to be interpreted by the intended shell.

Comment: Compare to `sudo -u user bash -c 'echo $BASH_VERSION'`, which tells you the version of bash in use (and will be empty for ksh). Notice how it's important to use single quotes so `$BASH_VERSION` isn't expanded until after `bash` was started.

Comment: Quoting from https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, which is where `SHELL` is specified: *This variable shall represent a pathname of the user's preferred command language interpreter*. `SHELL` does not tell you which shell is in use; it only tells you which shell is preferred by the user. Two completely different things.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy now I got. Answering your previous question, this is what happening: When I run `bash  atl.sh`  works perfectly, but when I just run `atl.sh` it don't. To run without bash, I need to run `/opt/atlante/bin/atl.sh`

Comment: This is why I thought the problem was about the bash

Comment: If you run `/opt/atlante/bin/atl.sh`, then the first line is used to decide which shell to use. Make sure it contains `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or similar; if it's `#!/bin/sh` then you aren't guaranteed bash-only features.

Comment: Got it. I checked the script, and it contains `#!/bin/bash -e`. Is this sufficient?